# Saving STK Scenario from Python app

Tags: python, stk-agi

I'm working with Python and STK integration. I need to build scenarios and save them, the problem is that I cannot find any saving example on [AGI's documentation](http://help.agi.com/stkdevkit/11.4.0/Content/stkObjects/ObjModPythonCodeSamples.htm). Here is a starting point:

```
import win32com.client

uiApplication = win32com.client.Dispatch('STK11.Application')
uiApplication.Visible = True

root = uiApplication.Personality2

root.NewScenario('this_Scenario')
satellite = root.CurrentScenario.Children.New(18, 'this_Satellite') # eSatellite

input("Press enter to exit script.")
```

How to tell STK to save the created scenario?

Comment: @DanPichelman : This is SpaceExploration.SE, I don't think there is a Space.SE. I did happen to post it before in Politics by accident.

Answer (score 5):

Your variable `root` is of type `IAgStkObjectRoot`.  If you search the [Programming Interface Help](http://help.agi.com/stkdevkit/index.htm#DocX/STKObjects~IAgStkObject~Root.html?Highlight=IAgStkObjectRoot), there are five save related methods for this type.  These include `Save()` and `SaveAs()`

So the easiest implementation would be:
`root.Save()` which will save the scenario in the `Documents\STK` folder.

If you want to control the specific location to save to you can try:
`root.SaveAs([FULL FILE NAME AND PATH])`