# Suggestion for software which allows orbit data generation under different conditions (such as J2, ATM drag etc)

Tags: orbit, python, spice

I am an amateur astrophysics enthusiast trying to generate orbit data.

What I want to achieve: I want to be able to generate orbits while only considering effects of (J2, J3, atm drag, solar pressure etc) , **separately**. Also I want to generate orbits and transitions for maneuvers such as Hohmann, bielliptic.

I just want to collect data at different points during the orbit.

I am mostly looking for 2 body simulation, such as a satellite around a planet.

I am searching for a **scriptable application in python**

Comment: To find orbits I was just using [oscelt](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/oscelt_c.html)  routine. I was using it random epochs (as data points). I didn't make it clear in the question but I am using it for validation only. (I have edited the question)

Comment: I don't understand your question; what does "I am unable to find any way to use perturbation (such as J2)" mean?. SPICE is not intended to produce orbits; it's only intended to use data files that usually include any kind of perturbation.

Comment: What I want to achieve: I want to be able to validate orbits with effects of J2, J3, atm drag, solar pressure (separately), maneuvers( Hohmann, bielliptic) mainly. I am searching for a scriptable application in python.

Comment: @AyushSuhane are you including a complete solar system, or do you just want one planet and the Sun (or one moon and a planet) in your universe? You're still not really describing the scope of the problem, **but in the mean time, go ahead and update your question with all of these things you've mentioned** and then we can clean up all these comments.

Comment: @AyushSuhane In the mean time, [here's how I use Python to calculate things](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102) but I think there will be better answers. I've added the Python tag to your question.

Comment: thank you @uhoh!

Comment: There are a large number of options you can look at in the many answers to the question [What are the choices today for orbital mechanics simulation software?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/646/12102) and you can look at GMAT and Poliastro in answers to [A software for orbit propagation, considering Moon, Sun and zonal harmonics](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28301/12102) as well as STK [Saving STK Scenario from Python app](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34329/12102)

Comment: See also [How does the poliastro python package “Going to Mars with Python” example work? What's it really doing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28228/12102)